# Firing a redirect from a Laravel event

Tags: redirect, laravel-5, events

I have a reset_password field within my users table that is set to '1' when a user account is created . When a user logs in I check this field and if set to '1' within an event. I want to redirect from the event if the field is set to '1'.

I have tried:

`return redirect()->route('user/change_password');`

and in my routes file I have set
`Route::get('user/change_password', 'UserController@resetpasswordform');`

but this returns an error of:

> InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 306: Route [user/change_password] not defined.

I have also tried this
`return redirect()->action('UserController@resetpasswordform');`

but this is just ignores the redirect and logs the user in. I have set a `dd('hello');` within the method but this does nothing.

I have tried changing the redirect for an authenticated user and if the field is not set to 1 then follows this redirect, but if the field is set to 1 it ignores this.

I am at a loss as to the route that this redirect is taking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied the postLogin class to my AuthController and theredirect to the method

```
if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
    if(Auth::user()->reset_password=='1'){
        return redirect()->action('UserController@resetpasswordform');
    }

    return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
}
```

Comment: so simply put: overwrite the traits that are used in the `LoginController` / `ResetController` when using laravel 5.3+

Answer (score 0):

```
return redirect('/user/change_password);
```

This works for me, try it.

Comment: unfortunately that does not work within an event. I have just found out that an event runs in the background and so a redirect cannot be fired from one. I will have to run the check within the auth controller and tehn fire the redirect.